# How to make Yammer post with with attachments using Powershell REST api

Tags: rest, api, powershell, yammer

```html
Function Post-YamBDMessage($UserEmail){
$uri = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"

$User = Get-YamUserByEmail($UserEmail)
$UserID = $User.id
$UserName=$User.first_name + " " + $User.last_name

$Payloadjson = '{
"body":"Today is [[user:'+$UserID+']]'+"'s Birthday"+'\n\nPlease help us in congratulating '+$User.first_name+'",
"group_id": '+$groupId+'
}'

$Headers = @{
"Accept" = "*/*"
"Authorization" = "Bearer "+$token
"accept-encoding" = "non"
"content-type"="application/json"
}

$res = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -Header $Headers -Body $Payloadjson
$Yamcontent = $res.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$Yammess = $Yamcontent.messages
$YamID = $Yammess.ID
$MesType = "1"

"{0},{1}" -f $YamID,$MesType | add-content -path $CSVPath
}

Function RemoveYamIDFromCSV($YamMessageID) {

$TempCSV = "C:\Temp\Temp_CSV.csv"

Import-Csv $CSVPath | where {$_.ID -ne $YamMessageID} | Export-Csv $TempCSV -notypeinfo

}
```

I am trying to create a Powershell script to post birthdays and anniversaries on Yammer. My script successfully posts messages on Yammer and tags the person the post is regarding.

But I would like to attach an image to the post. I have read the official documentation for the Yammer Rest API, but I cannot figure out how to attach an image to a post.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't go into much detail or contain any of the code you are using. Check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question that will get you a good answer.

Comment: Hi James, 

Sorry about that, it was indeed a busy friday :)

Here is my code for posting the birthday post


[link](https://lyngsoesystems-my.sharepoint.com/personal/lal_lyngsoesystems_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0175c4bb05c1f48eaa05a677a6b5baa80&authkey=AcmUNGC4484531mL_kNWBgo&expiration=2017-12-27T07%3A16%3A53.000Z&e=48f15ae423dd4c9b861a941372e54018)

Comment: You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47478281/edit) your question and paste you code as text, attaching a file isn't good practice here.

Comment: The Code is now also included in the post